# I cannot collect audit trail in AVDF 12. What's wrong?

Tags: oracle11g, audit, audit-trail

I installed Audit Vault Server 12 (DB Firewall not installed) in an Oracle Linux VM (VMware) and activated an agent for Oracle 11g Release 2 in Windows 7 x64 VM (VMware) 
according to *Oracle® Audit Vault and Database Firewall Installation Guide and Administrator’s Guide Release 12.1.0* as follows:

1) `ALTER SYSTEM SET AUDIT_TRAIL=XML, EXTENDED SCOPE=SPFILE;`
      Database restart.

2) Register the Oracle Database Host Machine.

3) Deploy Agent and Request Activation on the Host Machine.

4) Create user accounts on the secured targets and set up Oracle AVDF user privileges on an Oracle Database secured target.

5) Register Secured Targets in the Audit Vault Server with user account of stpe 4: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP:1521/orcl`

6) Configure an Audit Trail in the Audit Vault Server : TABLE - `sys.aud$` or `DVSYS.audit_trail$`, DIRECTORY - directory of audit trail in XML format are saved.

Every step seemed to be installed without any problems. 
I turned off firewall just in case.
The Administrator web page of AVDF showed only messages of "request completed" after having configured an Audit Trail in the Audit Vault Server.
But, the collection state was a red downward arrow, and even auditor web page showed same state.
I couldn't view audit trails in the auditor web page.
But, the vault option page (`https://IP:1158/dva`) showed audit trails in its report page.
What't wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the Agent's logs? There you can find for sure some information about your problem. In any case, it might be also the firewall. Try to stop the windows firewall, it might prevent the collector of the agent to collect data. Also, if you have set AUDIT_TRAIL=XML , you don't need to create a TABLE type Audit Trail.  Btw, you may have solved your problem. If it is the case, it would be nice from you to past your answer and check it as the right one. For other people who might be facing the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issues and after weeks of troubleshooting and redeployment of OAV agent, we figured out that there was a memory leak from OAV server side. SGA parameters at OAV server needs to be tuned properly. Your best bet is open an SR and work with Oracle because it's a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe orcl is the wrong db name

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP:1521/xxxx
```